# Validation request with Laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make validation with Laravel 5 on right way:

Here is my working code in model:

```
public function apiAddNewComment() {
        if (Input::get("task") == 'addComment') {
            $user = Auth::id();
            $inputs = array(
                'comment' => Input::get('comment'),
                'projectID' => Input::get('projectID'),
                'order' => Input::get("order"),
                'level' => Input::get("level"),
            );
            $rules = array(
                'comment' => 'required|between:15,600',
                'projectID' => "required|exists:project_group,project_id,user_id,$user|numeric",
                'order' => "required|numeric",
                'level' => "required|numeric"
            );

            $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return json_encode(array('err' => true, 'errors' => $validator->messages()->all()));
            } else {
                return $this->createNewComment();
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my controller:

```
public function update($id, Comment $update)
    {
                return $update->apiUpdateComment();

    }
```

How can I make validation with `request`?

And can someone explain me how this method works inside request:

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

?

Comment: The [Form Request Validation Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation) is pretty self explanatory. If that's not enough, you can always watch the [Laracasts video tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Request` has to basic functions: `rules()` and `authorize()`

rules returns an array that is used for the validation.

The authorize method can for example check if the user is allowed to do this request.

```
public function authorize() {
    return Auth::check();
}
```

So you don't have to check it each time when you use the request in a controller.

If you need no check just return `true`.

**UPDATE:**
Generate a request File with artisan

```
php artisan make:request CommandRequest
```

then edit the generate file like this:

```
class CommandRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'comment' => 'required|between:15,600',
            'projectID' => "required|exists:project_group,project_id,user_id,$user|numeric",
            'order' => "required|numeric",
            'level' => "required|numeric"
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also update the controller method:

```
public function update($id, Comment $update, CommandRequest $request)
{
    // create your comment here like:
    return Comment::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: But how can I inplement it in my example, I need to validate fields from my ajax request... I need to validate `$inputs` array..

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure if it works 100% but this should be the right way.

Comment: I don't need to create comment I need to update.... Also I need to check rules against ajax fileds `Input::get(...)` ....

Comment: then use `Comment::find($id)->update($request->all());`. By using the CommandRequest class it will be checked.

Comment: This video is useful to understand useage of requests https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/3

Comment: you have the parameter `request`in your update function because it's a post request. By using `CommandRequest` the validation will be done. Check out the video to understand it.

Comment: Aha, but what if I want to validate all fileds and update just some?

Comment: Then you do `Comment::find($id)->update(['comment' => $request->get('comment'));`

Comment: Nice, this will also validate other fields?

Comment: The request class will to the validation

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Laravel 4 code I guess, you need to translate it to L5 where `Input::get('var')` turns into `$request->input('var')` for instance:

```
public function apiAddNewComment(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) { //Remember to add the Request as a parameter of the method
        if ($request->input("task") == 'addComment') {
...
```

Then the validation part looks fine